# How do I transfer funds from MY OWN card to MY OWN personal bank account?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, banking, bank-account, debit-card

Would anyone please be so kind to explain me how (where) could I transfer funds from my own debit and/or credit (particularly debit) card issued by X bank (USA) to my own personal checking bank account owned in Y bank (USA)? I would like to particularly emphasize that I am NOT asking for suggestions to use alternative options such as wires, ach, ewallets, cash deposit. I had to emphasize this so someone wouldn't tell me to just log in and do some internal transfer between own accounts. On both, card and bank account is my own name. Balance Transfer won't work because it is between card only. Cash advance (ATM) won't be solution either. What else could I do? I am asking only for my own assets but unfortunately in two different banks.

Comment: Is your Bank X debit card prepaid?

Comment: Could you clarify why all the normal, proscribed, officially supported options won't work for you? ACH and wire exist explicitly for bank to bank transfers, but there are no funds "on/in" debit (unless prepaid) or credit cards, but rather act as a tool to transfer using intermediary banks (credit processors) and aren't free. It is hard to know what to suggest without knowing why the normal methods are off the table. Affordability? Bank won't let you? Convenience? Can't write a check to yourself from an associated checking account? Etc.

Comment: ACH isn't an "alternative option". It's *the* option for transferring between checking accounts at different banks.

Comment: @BrianH that and "I am asking only for my own assets" strike me as the kinds of questions that immigrant or foreign scammers ask when trying to develop as scam.

Answer (score 12):

This answer is predicated upon your `Bank X` Debit Card **not** being prepaid.

> Would anyone please be so kind to explain me how (where) could I transfer funds from my own debit

Since a debit card is directly tied to a bank account, it doesn't make sense to transfer money from a DC to a bank account.

> and/or **credit** (particularly debit) **card** issued by X bank (USA) to my own personal checking bank account owned in Y bank (USA)?

That would be a cash advance.  Cash advances are **Very Expensive**.

> I would like to particularly emphasize that I am NOT asking for suggestions to use alternative options such as wires, ach

Why not?

> Cash advance (ATM) won't be solution either.

But that's what getting money from your credit card **is**.

The bottom line is that your question indicates some deeply fundamental misunderstandings about the US banking system.

Answer (score 7):

Bank cards are like keys to a house. They grant access to the stuff inside but don’t themselves contain that stuff.

When you deposit money at a bank, the bank takes your money and credits it to your *account*. You can then access those funds via various ‘keys’ - cards, internet banking, passbooks, etc.

When you have an account at another bank, that’s like having stuff in another house. Bringing your old key to the new house isn’t the same thing as bringing the furniture along.

tl;dr: It doesn’t make sense to talk about transfer of funds from one bank to another without the funds going from one *account* to another.

Answer (score 0):

A debit card, which is linked to a bank account, is just one of the ways to make a payment from that bank account.

However, the card can only be used to make a payment to someone who has a **merchant account** which allows reception of card payments. A merchant account is for businesses, and the holder of the merchant account will have to **pay a commission** on each payment they receive (in addition to setup and monthly costs, in most cases).

The funds you can use with your debit card are actually in the bank account. So **the real good solution to make a payment from one bank account to another is to make a bank transfer/wire/ACH from one account to the other**. Depending on the bank(s), the type of account, the type of transfer, this may be free or incur a fee, though the fee is usually small nowadays if there is one.

An alternative is to use your debit card to withdraw money from your bank account using an ATM (subject to any fees levied by the ATM and/or the bank for such a withdrawal) and then deposit the money into the other bank account (possibly subject to fees as well).

Yet another alternative is to use a good old-fashioned check, if you still have a check book. Yet again, there may be fees on either side.

If your are talking about a different type of card such as a prepaid card, then it may be possible you can't access the funds via other means than using the card, though you should probably double check, many prepaid cards actually provide alternatives. If you can indeed only use the card to access the funds, then alternatives include:

- withdrawing the money at an ATM, if the card allows it, which would probably incur fees
- it may be possible to add the card to a Paypal account or other similar payment services provider and use it to fund a payment to your account (though this may be restricted to sending money to someone else rather than withdrawing to your own account). There will probably be fees to be paid as well.
- You can open a Transferwise Borderless account, and add funds using the card. There are fees for that, though (0.75% from a debit card, 3.4% from a credit card), and then more fees to send the money to the destination bank account.

The same applies for a credit card, though you usually don't have a positive balance on a credit card, and this would most definitely be a cash advance, which is subject to yet more fees (and interest).

Answer (score 0):

You could use PayPal, register there your IBANs [PANs] and transfers from IBAN1 [PAN1] to PayPal (PayPal top-up) and then from PayPal to IBAN2 [PAN2] (Transfer).

If you use cards I think you have to transfer at least 100$ (here is 100€) to have the transaction for free.

But if yours are debit card (that are linked to a plain old bank account) why you don't just do a money transfer between "underlaying" accounts, most banks offer those for free.

NOTE: it works if accounts are different, if your card is linked to the same IBAN you want to transfer to it does not make sense because card are "taking money" from the same pool you want to splash money into.